# angularjs form validation showing success on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

I have a function in my controller to validate if maximum of three choices are made out of available checkboxes and one free text area. The user can either choose three checkboxes and leave the text area empty, or can choose two checkboxes and type in some text in the text area. A combination of three is allowed.
This field is `required`, the user must choose a combination of three.
The function itself is working, but the validation is showing success!
The problem is when the page is loaded, all the options go green and the success message is shown, whereas the user has not even clicked on any part of it.

Here is the html code:

```
<form name="Form">
    <div class="form-group" >
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':Form.cooptype.$dirty && Form.cooptype.$invalid, 'has-success':Form.cooptype.$valid}">
        <label class="control-label" translate="list.cooporationtype">
            Type(s) of project<span class="symbol required"></span>
        </label>
        :<br/>
        <div ng-repeat="topic in list.cooperationtypelist">
            <div > {{topic.item}}</div>
            <ul >
                <li ng-repeat="subitem in topic.subitems">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="cooptype"
                           ng-disabled="checkboxDisable(subitem.key)"
                           ng-model="myModel.cooperationtype[subitem.key]">
                            {{subitem.values | translate}}

                </li>

            </ul>
            <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="Form.cooptype.$dirty && Form.cooptype.$error.required">Field is required.</span>
            <span class="success text-small" ng-if="Form.cooptype.$valid">Done!</span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':Form.cooptypetext.$dirty && Form.cooptypetext.$invalid, 'has-success':Form.cooptypetext.$valid}">
            <p>or type it in yourself:</p>

            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="cooptypetext" placeholder="Enter the cooperation type (max of 100 characters)"
                      ng-model="myModel.cooperationtype.coopfreetext"
                      ng-disabled="checkboxDisable('cooptypetext')"
                      ng-minlength=5
                      ng-maxlength=100></textarea>
            <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="Form.cooptypetext.$error.maxlength">Too long!</span>
            <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="Form.cooptypetext.$error.minlength">Too short!</span>
            <span class="success text-small" ng-if="Form.cooptypetext.$valid">Done!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

here is the function in my controller:

```
$scope.myModel.cooperationtype = {};
$scope.checkboxDisable = function(key) {
    if(!$scope.myModel.cooperationtype[key]) {
        var count = 0;
        Object.keys($scope.myModel.cooperationtype).forEach(function(key) {
            if($scope.myModel.cooperationtype[key]) {
                ++count;
            }
        });

        if(count >= 3) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check to make sure that the fields are dirty, aka the user has typed some input into them, in addition to being valid.  You also need to use ng-form, and not divs

Comment: as i told, on the page load, without even user not seen the fields yet! the fields go green and show success under the field.

Comment: Yes, because unless you check if the forms are dirty, the validation correctness will be triggered.  You also need to use a form element

Comment: You need to use ng-form, not divs.  you keep referring to Form., but Form doesn't exist anywhere.  Check this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform

Comment: i don't get the point, can you suggest a working answer to this question?

Comment: In order to use form validations, you need to use forms, and not divs.  I suggest that you take a look at that link, which will explain how to use forms to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: if you are talking about the form `<form name="Form">` I had omitted it in the post, because my form is long so I extracted the relevant part, so I simply forgot to mention it.

Comment: you need to use ng-form, not form.  Again, check that page and you will very quickly be able to see what you are doing wrong